# Missing basic packages like pkg_add?

Tags: freebsd

I recently performed a fresh install of 10.1-RELEASE (amd/x64_86) due to a [botched upgrade](https://superuser.com/q/919948/173513). It seems like I'm missing basic utilities, like `pkg_add`. `find / -name pkg_add` is returning 0 hits (even when run as root). `ports` and `portmaster` seems to be missing too (the only hit is in `usr/ports/port-mgmt/portmaster`, and its a directory and not a program.

---

When I try to run the following to boot strap it:

```
setenv PACKAGESITE pkg.us-east.FreeBSD.org
pkg
```

Results in:

```
pkg: Error fetching pkg.us-east.FreeBSD.org/Latest/pkg.txz: Invalid URL scheme.
```

But according to [Official FreeBSD Binary Packages now available for pkgng](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-pkg/2013-October/000107.html) its supposed to just work...

I've also tried using setting `PACKAGESITE` `ports-mgmt/pkg`; and setting `PACKAGEROOT` and `ftp://ftp3.FreeBSD.org` with no joy.

---

Also, this was not helpful: [pkg_add: command not found](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/commands-not-found.25069/). It does not seem to be a path problem because it cannot be found with `find`.

---

Why was a package manager not installed by default? Or why does it not work (am I doing something obviously wrong)???

How do I install the basic packages, like `pkg_add`?

Sorry about the basic question. `pkg_add` is what I ***use*** to install packages, so I'm a bit lost when its missing.

Comment: Most of these issues were resolved by fixing `/etc/resolv.conf`. It had a bogus nameserver listed. I'm not sure what went wrong here because I clearly did not add that 172.16.*.* address. `pkg_add` is still missing. So I cant install emacs, and I'm stuck with that miserable vi (for the moment).

Answer (score 4):

FreeBSD 10 uses the new Packagetool pkg instead of pkg_add.

See
https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html

Answer (score 3):

`pkg install pkg` and let it bootstrap / upgrade itself. Then use `pkg install foo`, etc. `pkg_add` does not exist anymore, as you've found out.

I will second https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html .